# Regular Expression to just complete word C#

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to know how to extract complete words using a Regex in C#

For example, my String input:

```
This$#23 is-kt     jkdls
```

I want to get Regex Match as

1. `This$#23`
2. `is-kt`
3. `jkdls`

I need to extract non space words [which can have numbers or special characters]

by specifying Regex Match pattern

```
Regex myrex = new Regex("pattern")
```

Comment: If you want to match non-space characters, use `@"\S+"`.

Comment: thanks but, i need to extract non space words [which can have numbers special characters]

Comment: ...Which is exactly what @falsetru's suggestion will do. Note the `+`.

Comment: can you show us what you have tried and why that did not work?

Comment: m_regex = new Regex("(\\S+)", options);

Comment: Match m_match = this.m_regex.Match(Text);

Comment: once if i match to verify this in while loop, i retrieve m_match.Value as character wise

Comment: so how can i retrieve, entire word as match.Value

Comment: @stu, if you can solve this requirement easily i will accept this as home work..... just because i have asked this requirement that does not mean i dont know Regex

Comment: Can you add a complete code example, with test input and results, to your question, instead of lines here and there in the comments? If there's a problem with your code, not your regex, we can troubleshoot that.

Comment: I already solved the problem as stated. The requirement for it to be a regex is artificial.

Answer (score 2):

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches("This$#23 is-kt     jkdls", @"\S+");
    foreach(Match match in matches)
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Use \S+ to match words.

Answer (score 0):

`var words = string.Split(' ');`

Comment: @user2700767 why do you need it in regex? Doesn't this solve your issue?

Comment: no because i need to give as Regex myrex = new Regex("my pattern")

Comment: @user2700767 we are here to help you solve the problem that you present. the problem you have presented is splitting words in a string, which this solves efficiently and easily readable. You asking for a Regex in this context is similar to asking "I want to eat soup using a fork. How can I solve this using a fork?" and this answer being "use a spoon"

Comment: Why does it NEED to be a Regex? You're not asking us to do homework for you, are you?

Comment: please don't mistake me, i have been trying to achieve this since one week and yet i could not find solution .... this is my primary requirement... that's why please understand

Comment: No. Why is it a primary requirement?

Comment: i need to do text parsing in my custom text control, that y

Comment: @user2700767 You can parse text in the way you've asked using `Split()`. If you have requirements imposed on you by someone else, including a course instructor, that's fine, but the reasoning behind the requirement is relevant because if the reasoning is faulty, the requirement should be removed.